# Writing async/await version of a callback

Tags: node.js, async-await, kurento

I'm trying to rewrite a `callback` as `async/await` but following code doesn't work and results in high CPU at the commented line.

```
const kurento = require('kurento-client')

function getKurentoClient (kmsUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    kurento(kmsUrl, (error, kurentoClient) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      } else {
        return resolve(kurentoClient) // never returns
      }
    })
  })
}

async function test () {
  let result = await getKurentoClient('ws://localhost:8888/kurento')
  console.log('done')
}

test()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: @KevinBurdett: For sure I have tried every available solution in SO without any chance, maybe missing an important point.

Comment: gotcha, I flagged it due to work related-reflex :) The code looks sound to me. I always recommend using [promisify from the Node.JS API](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) in place of an instantiated promise. However, the code looks sound. I would start looking at the kurento client/server setup (which I know nothing about).

Comment: do you have a functional sample using callbacks? perhaps something important was lost in the translation?

Comment: @KevinBurdett: The `callback` version works fine. I get `kurentoClient` at the commented line (using breakpoint, it is there after a while) but code execution ends there and nothing returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [mozilla.org website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. **If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable**, adopting its eventual state; if the value was a promise, that object becomes the result of the call to Promise.resolve; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

And from [bluebird GitHub](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/833):

> when promises resolve other promises or things with `then`(aka `then`ables, like `_kurentoClient` in this case) - they have to wait for it to call `then` itself.

As you have guessed, kurento clients have a `then` function (so is a thenable) so the Promise is trying to resolve it. Because of a bug (or not a bug. Honestly, I have not researched enough to determine that) it keeps resolving itself forever.

As far as I see, seems that [this kurento commit](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-client-js/commit/b06ef2c42d42047caabb49668535263aa7d7b440#diff-ea3e1858c081563f64dbece2fb93f1b8R951) tries to fix it, resolving to an "untheanble". I see that the commit is from `31 Oct 2016` but the latest release is from `Sep 2016` so I think that the fixed version is not deployed.